# How do I render the vuex module in nuxt before rendering the middleware

Tags: javascript, vue.js, authorization, vuex, nuxt.js

my problem is that, when the page is reloaded, the middleware first renders, then the vuex; so, when I want to change a value in the vuex, based on whether the user is authenticated or not, the middleware returns the initial value of the vuex. This means that, if the user is authenticated, it first shows false, and after the vuex is rendered, it then displays true. But by then, the middleware has finished loading. And this results in redirecting the user to the login page, anytime the page is refreshed. My question is that, is they a way I can load the vuex first before the middleware?

here is the middleware code;

```
export default async function ({ store, redirect }) {
  // If the user is not authenticated
  const authenticated = await store.state.signup.authenticated
  if (!authenticated) {
    console.log(!authenticated)
    return redirect('/login')
  } else {
    console.log('I am logged in')
  }
}
```

here is the vuex code;

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const state = () => ({
  authenticated: false,
  credential: null,
})

export const mutations = {
  ADD_USER(state, data) {
    state.credential = data
    state.authenticated = true
  },
  LOGOUT(state) {
    state.credential = null
    state.authenticated = false
  },
}

export const actions = {
  async addUser({ commit }, data) {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        'http://localhost:8000/api/rest-auth/registration/',
        data
      )
      commit('ADD_USER', response.data)
      this.$router.push('/')
    } catch (error) {
      return console.log(error)
    }
  },

  async addUserLogin({ commit }, data) {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        'http://localhost:8000/api/rest-auth/login/',
        data
      )
      commit('ADD_USER', response.data)
      this.$router.push('/')
    } catch (error) {
      return console.log(error)
    }
  },
}

export const getters = {
  loggedIn(state) {
    return !!state.credential
  },
}
```

here is the login.vue code

```
<template>
  <client-only>
    <div class="container">
      <v-card max-width="500" class="margin-auto">
        <v-card-title>Sign up</v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>
          <v-form @submit.prevent="submitUser">
            <v-text-field
              v-model="data.username"
              label="Username"
              hide-details="auto"
              append-icon="account_circle"
            ></v-text-field>
            <v-text-field
              v-model="data.password"
              label="Password"
              hide-details="auto"
              type="password"
              append-icon="visibility_off"
            ></v-text-field>
            <v-card-actions>
              <v-btn color="success" type="submit" class="mt-4" dark>
                Signup
              </v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-form>
          <p>
            Don't have an account? <nuxt-link to="/signup">Register</nuxt-link>
          </p>
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </div>
  </client-only>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      data: {
        username: '',
        password: '',
      },
    }
  },

  methods: {
    submitUser() {
      this.$store.dispatch('signup/addUserLogin', this.data)
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.margin-auto {
  margin: 2rem auto;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I suggest you to use the nuxt auth package for authentication purpose, please look into this for once: https://auth.nuxtjs.org/.

Comment: How is your store going to contain any data if the page is refreshed? Are you using the localstorage for storing the previous state of the user? Ideally this isn't the case that you've mentioned we can access the store inside a middleware too . Please look into this: https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-middleware/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do that ! In fact, the store is already available in your middleware. But in your case, the store is empty ! You need to fetch the data before and fill the store.

I suggest you to read the document on the nuxt middleware https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#middleware. It states that

> A middleware can be asynchronous. To do this, simply return a Promise or use the 2nd callback argument.

So in your case, you need to return a Promise in your middleware : this promise will be the axios request. Here is a proposition :

```
export default function ({ store, redirect }) {
    return new Promise(resolve => store.dispatch('signup/addUserLogin', data).then((user) => {
        if (!user) {
            // User not found
            redirect('/login');
        } else {
            // Do your stuff with the user freshly got, like commit in the store
            resolve();
        }
    })
}
```

In your case, you should modify the action `addUserLogin` : you should only get the axios query in this function, not the redirect.
Moreover, you will have a problem with the data used in the action, password and user. When you refresh, you loose this data. You should implement a system of token, like JWT, and store them in the local storage or in the cookies (like in this example https://nuxtjs.org/examples/auth-external-jwt/).

Hope that helps you !